# How to set optional parameters using Django?

Tags: python, django, view

I need to set optional parameters using Django. I try a method saw on Stack Overflow but it didn't work.

My code :

views.py :

```
 def get(self, request, id_document, optional_parameters = 'owner'):
  #code here
```

urls.py :

```
url(r'^getdoclist/(?P<id_document>[^/]+)/$', Get_DocumentList.as_view()),
url(r'^getdoclist/(?P<id_document>[^/]+)/(?P<owner>[^/]+)/$', Get_DocumentList.as_view()),
```

it didn't work using this method :(

Thanks if you could help me

Answer (score 1):

You need to use opitional parameter like this:

```
def get(self, request, id_document, owner=None):  # owner=any other value
```

Or

```
def get(self, request, id_document, **kwargs):
   owner = self.kwargs.get('owner', None)
```

Alternativly, you can consider [URL querystring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). Then you do not need to define two urls in `urls.py`, but you can still get the value, like this:

```
def get(self, request, id_document, **kwargs):
   owner = request.GET.get('owner')
```

Then you need to call the url like this:

```
localhost:8000/getdoclist/1234567890/?owner=SomeOne
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                         document id   owner value after question mark
```

Comment: thanks for your anwer ! but when i set two parameters in the url it did'nt work

Comment: Sorry, what do mean by two parameters? Can you please add an example?